PyImport_Import does not import functions
I'm doing some code that allows plugin authors for our software to embed python code in their plugins. And I'm stuck with some strange import behavior.
When I import this simple python file with PyImport_Import, I expect that the resulting PyObject will have attribute test which is callable, and also some attributes like __name__ and so on.
def test(x, y):
    return x+y

Instead, results of PyObject_Dir shows only __something__ attributes and no test. And it's not just PyObject_Dir, when I try to access test by name, it's not found too.
This is how my code looks like (error checking removed for readability)
    PyObject* sysModule = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
    PyObject* sysPath = PyObject_GetAttrString(sysModule, "path");
    PyObject* objPath = PyUnicode_FromString(modulePath.c_str());
    PyList_Append(sysPath, objPath);
    Py_XDECREF(objPath);
    Py_DECREF(sysPath);

    PyObject_SetAttrString(sysModule, "dont_write_bytecode", Py_True);
    Py_DECREF(sysModule);

    PyObject* modName = PyUnicode_FromString(name.c_str());
    PyObject* module = PyImport_Import(modName);
    Py_DECREF(modName);

    PyObject* contents = PyObject_Dir(module);

    auto size = PyList_Size(contents);
    for (auto index = 0; index < size; ++index)
    {
        PyObject* itemName = PyList_GetItem(contents, index);
        PyObject* item = PyObject_GetAttr(module, itemName);
        if (!item)
        {
            continue;
        }

        PyObject* bytes = PyUnicode_AsUTF8String(itemName);
        std::string strName = PyBytes_AsString(bytes);
        Py_DECREF(bytes);
        log(strName);

        if (PyCallable_Check(item))
        {
            log("Callable!");
        }
        Py_DECREF(item);
    }

When I import this file from python console, everything is fine. Module object is not null. What else can be wrong?
I suppose it might be related to the fact that I'm doing this inside a sub-interpreter. But I failed to find any documentation explaining this: all I found is explaining that imported modules are different between sub-interpreters, but no indication that import itself works differently in this case.

Note that allowing clients to run their own arbitrary code opens up a lot of potential problems you may find yourself helping to debug. Proceed cautiously.

Sure it's dangerous, but just as dangerous as VBA macros in Excel. :-)

Check the __file__. See if you're really importing what you think you are.

It's unlikely to be your issue, but why, given that you have easy access to the module name as a C string, are you using PyImport_Import() instead of PyImport_ImportModule() to import it?

Thamk you! That's true, if you call your module test.py, you would be importing system package test. Changed PyList_Append(sysPath, objPath) to PyList_Insert(sysPath, 0, objPath) and it worked as expected.
